# Java Mustache error: No method or field with name 'name'

Tags: java, templates, mustache, templating

I'm trying to make templating on Mustache for Java Spring and have a problem.

I send such JSONArray of JSONObjects:

```
[{name: 'foo', age: 21}, {name: 'bar', age: 22}]
```

And I wrote this template:

```
<ul>{{#data}}<li>{{.}}</li>{{/data}}</ul>
```

- It's okay, it works. It just shows whole objects from my array.

But I need only specific fields (here is just an example, real objects are bigger) and I need such template:

```
<ul>{{#data}}<li>{{name}}</li>{{/data}}</ul>
```

- But this doesn't work. I get an error: **No method or field with name 'name'**
  Every single element of array is JSONObject and every of them has an field "name". I can see it when I print them with {{.}}

What am I doing here wrong and how should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: try this Json  { data:[{name: 'foo', age: 21}, {name: 'bar', age: 22}] }

Comment: @FLYFLU, it didn't work, I have the same error